# How to calculate the average above the 80% in excel?

Tags: excel

How to calculate the average of the 80 percentile to 100 percentile of a column, I try to use the `averageif()` functions, but it only support the condition `">1"` instead of a formula condition `>percentile(A1:A100,80)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is almost correct.  Just some minor syntax issues.  Try:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A100,">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A100,80%))
```